# ASP.NET MVC3 - DropDownList Refreshes Model using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a drop down list that, when changed, should refresh the model for the view.  Here is the controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       //do something totally awesome
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(int user)
    {
        //do something even more awesome with the new value selected from the drop down list 
    }
```

The relevant part of the View:

```
<div id="selectuser" class="user-input">@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedUser, Model.Users)</div>
```

and the jQuery to handle the drop down list changing:

```
$(function () {
    $('#selectuser select').change(function () {
        $.post('@Url.Action("Index", "Home")', { user: $(this).val() }, function (result) {

        });
    });
});
```

It appears that everything is working, except the jQuery part.  Evidently, the UrlAction(...) isn't right.  When a user changes the selection, this is the URL MVC tries to load: http://localhost:5555/@Url.Action%28%22Index%22,%20%22Home%22%29

I was expecting MVC to route to the HttpPost Index action in the controller when a selection changed.  Why didn't it?  How do I fix it?

I'm a total noob at this - your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening here is that the Razor engine isn't evaluating @Url.Action(). If I had to guess, I'd say that whatever is generating the JavaScript code isn't in the same razor view. If you haven't already, I'd start by moving the code into a  block on the view page, if you haven't already. It's not clear from the original post whether the JQuery code is in the view or not.

Comment: That was it!  Thank you.  The script was in another file.  After moving the script into a <script> tag in the view, it worked.  I'm not sure why it matters where the JS lives, but evidently it does matter.

Comment: It matters because the Razor engine only sees files that are processed through a controller. So if you wrote an action that returned JavaScript, that would work - but if you just have a plain .js file the web server just sends that right onto the browser without any additional processing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ajax to call back to the function?

```
$('#selectuser select').change(function () {
   $.ajax({
       url: '@Url.Content("~/Home/Index")',
       type: "POST",
       data: val,
       datatype: "json",
       success: function (data, status, request) {
           // success code here
       },
       error: function (request, status, error) {
           // error code here
       }
    });
}
```

Here would be an example of a controller function (Index) that returns JSON:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Index(int val)
{
    try
    {
        // do what you need to here

        return Json(new
        {
             // Returning a partial view and success
             Html = this.RenderPartialView("_PartialView", model),
             Success = true
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
        return Json(new
        {
             // Returning a partial view and and error
             Html = this.RenderPartialView("_PartialView", model),
             Success = false
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

I added some more examples below incase you must use an ActionResult and can't use a JsonResult.

http://blogs.us.sogeti.com/swilliams/2009/05/11/different-action-results-with-asp-net-mvc-and-jquery/

http://iridescence.no/post/Invoking-ASPNET-MVC-Actions-from-JavaScript-using-jQuery.aspx

[Return ActionResult to a Dialog. ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579927/return-actionresult-to-a-dialog-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm not sure how adding ajax would help.  Alas, I tried using the script above and set a breakpoint in my existing controller that never gets hit.  The error was basically the same (HTTP 500) because this is the URL it is trying to open: http://localhost:5555/@Url.Content%28%22~/Home/Index%22%29

Comment: I think you are missing something in your MVC 3 app. It should not come out like that. Try creating a new MVC 3 app and see if it still occurs.

Comment: Agreed with TIHan, there's no reason your url should look like that. Do you have all the necessary jquery references in your project? Have you put a breakpoint in your jQuery to see what exactly it's doing? Is your jQuery in the ready or pageLoad function?

Comment: Also, I'm confused why you're using the id of the div. You should try putting an id on your dropdownlist itself... such as : 

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedUser, Model.Users, new {id = "ddlUser"})

and use this as reference to grab your val and trigger your jquery